# jqBootstrapValidation + AJAX : Without a <form> or submit button

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I would like to use jqBootstrapValidation to validate `<input>` elements (type=text) without having a submit button. Basically, I am using Bootstrap + AngularJS. So, there is a lot of code in the AngularJS controller. I do not want to submit any form. Although I have div elements with `class="form-horizontal"`, these aren't really `<form>` elements.

Is there a general way of doing this with jqBootstrapValidation?

Sample Markup:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-offset-1">
         <label id="lblDesc">Description</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtDesc" name="Desc" data-validation-ajax-ajax="/Draft/Validate" data-element-name="Desc" data-ng-model="Desc" />
                                    </div>
</div
```